# mysql DATE range BETWEEN Query

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have some very odd behaviour from a MySQL query in my C# application which is pulling rows from a Table called project_info. It should retrieve all the Rows which Equal the Customer's Name, and the project start date is BETWEEN the DATE range in the query. The current query I am using works but the date range appears to behave very oddly...

For example if I have a Row in my Table which contains a project for Customer 'WHSmith' and they have a project with a start date of '30/07/2018' when I search with a date range BETWEEN 18/06/2018 AND 01/08/2018 the query returns no results, but if I repeat the query using a date range BETWEEN 18/06/2018 AND 02/08/2018 the Row is returned???

The query I currently have is:

```
SELECT * FROM project_info WHERE cust_name = "WHSmith" AND proj_date BETWEEN 2018-06-18 AND 2018-08-01;
```

The date is stored as a DATE field in the table so no Time is included in the query or the value... The cust_name and dates are held in variables within my application but I have checked these are correct and seem OK.
Does anyone have any idea why the BETWEEN query is behaving so oddly? or maybe suggest a better way to look for Row's in a DATE range... many thanks.

Comment: Show your code. The query you show has no quotes around the date.

Comment: Can you try using quotes for date ?
SELECT * FROM project_info WHERE cust_name = "WHSmith" AND proj_date BETWEEN '2018-06-18' AND '2018-08-01';

Comment: It'd be extremely helpful to see your code and the schema for the table you're querying. If you're building this query with Oracle Connector/NET, you may be running into this bug (or a variant of it): https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80011 in which case you may wish to consider switching to an alternative ADO.NET library: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys... I have discovered that my constructor for the query was formatting the dates slightly incorrectly... Still unsure how it was working over a bigger date range but after putting the formatting within the variables right it behaved as expected. Sorry for the lack of code but I am pulling variables from within my application which would have been meaningless to you for reviewing here.... many thanks.